# force sbt to show compiler stack trace

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt to compile a project. And scala compiler crashes while compiling. Sbt shows tiny record about assertion. How can I get full compiler stack trace?

I've tried to search this question in google but finds only cases when your own code or test cases crashes, not scala compiler itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat the same command, but preceded with `last`. For example, if you tried `compile` and something happened, type `last compile` next.

In addition, sbt keeps all the logs files from various tasks under `target/streams` directory.   It is in a directory corresponding to the scope/task executed.   SO, `compile/compile/$out` contains the logs for running compile.

When you see an error, it should tell you *which task* failed so that you can either go look up the logs, or run `last <cmd that failed>`.   If you do a `grep -R "MyException" target/streams` in your project directory it should find the right logfile.

Comment: I've tried to do so. I've got nothing more than assertion failed message. There is no stack trace in sbt last compile